# Android 4.3 Paint.paintStyle() being ignored, sometimes

Tags: android, canvas, path, paint, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Im am currently experiencing a very strange problem with Android 4.3. The problem arrises when i draw a path with the paint.setStyle() set to Paint.Style.STROKE or Paint.Style.FILL. See below:

[image: Test #1 on 4.3]

[image: Test #2 on 4.3]

The same paint object being used among everything that is drawn. It is reset and new parameters set on every new layer that is draw (grid lines, text, chart lines, etc...). **The paint parameters are hardcoded and there should be absolutely no difference in either test 1 or 2**. The proper drawing behavior can be found below(test 3 = Android 4.2.2).

[image: Test #3 on 4.2.2]

If anyone has a clue as to where I could even begin to fix this, while still using paths, id appreciate it.

Comment: Might be a hardware acceleration issue. A lot of things changed for HW Acceleration between API 17 and 18. You could try, in `onAttachedToWindow()` and `onDetachedFromWindow()` in your custom view, respectively, calling 'setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` and `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE)` as a quick sanity check to see if that's behind the issue.

Comment: Interesting. Whenever I do anything with the view (moving across the screen), i had set the layerType to LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, then when the view was resting i set it back to LAYER_TYPE_NONE.

Comment: @kcoppock I did this is to avoid redraw and avoiding another method of creating and drawing to a bitmap and getting a OutOfMemoryException at times. BTW, setting the layerType in onAttach and onDetach fixes the issue. Its just that now i have to implement a different way to handle unwanted redraw since setting LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE is now useless.

Comment: What you should probably do is when moving the view across the screen, just set the layer type to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE instead of LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, and that should fix your issue, although it may be less performant. I'd be interested to see some of your drawing calls to see if it's an unsupported hardware acceleration call or something.

Comment: I just found another situation where HW acceleration behaves differently in 4.3. Suppose you drawRect(1,1,100,100), it looks all right to the human eye since (1,1) is on the "top" **but** Android thinks a "top" point _shall have a larger Y coordinate_ (so, to the eye it's the _bottom_-left point, (1,100) ). So, Hardware acceleration expects drawRect(1,100,100,1) and if you feed (1,1,100,100), it's going to do interesting things.

Comment: What drawRect(1,1,100,100) results in is: it will **NOT** be drawn on my Touchpad+4.3. It's drawn on other Android versions, however, including 4.3 on the simulator and 4.1 or 2.3 on a phone, if it's _entirely bounded by the canvas_ ..... This webpage refers to the "top" as a "quirkyness": http://uberpython.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/android-api-quirk-number-5/ ... I guess this may be that switching top and bottom values causes the 3D pipeline to see triangles with opposite normal directions. The pipeline must be _culling away_ primitives with one of these normal directions.